# Renew short lived access_token for a long time

Tags: php, security, oauth, token, access-token

Let me explain the title :

I have a **PHP API** using OAuth2 authentication.

I have a **NodeJS application**,using this API via Password Grant. In session, the node stores access token and refresh token per user.

I have no trouble renewing the access_token with the refresh_token, when the user is requesting the node or via a front end demon, asking node to refresh regularly.

My question is :
I would like to keep my access_token short lived as I heard it was a further security (3600 sec or so), but I would like to allow the user to come back a few days later and still be authenticated, or at least avoiding asking him password login once more. Am I forced to make the access token lifetime longer ?
Does the Node Server need to refresh the user's token even if he's not requesting anything ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many common OAuth2 implementations refresh tokens are valid for a long time (much longer than the access token) or do not expire at all. You need to store this refresh token linked to your node session (For instance in DB). Then, when the user is coming back, just retrieve a new access token using the related refresh token.

According to http://blog.cloud-elements.com/oauth-2-0-access-refresh-token-guide:

- Box

  - Access token: 1 hour
  - Refresh token: 60 days (resets 60 days when retrieving new access token)
- Dropbox

  - Access token: Forever
  - Refresh token: N/A
- Google DriveGoogle Drive OAuth

  - Access token: 1 hour, from my experience, but it seems this can vary depending on the Google API (expires_in field is returned in JSON)
  - Refresh token: Forever
- OneDrive

  - Access token: 1 hour
  - Refresh token: 6 months (Get a new one every time you call refresh)
- SharePoint

  - Access token: 1 hour
  - Refresh token: 6 months (Get a new one every time you call refresh)

Answer (score 0):

A refresh token can not expire or can have a very long time expiration.